# Debug: How to print bibtex key? (Like showkeys prints labels?)

Tags: bibtex, debugging

I want to print the bibtex key being cited, just like the `showkeys` package prints the label names, above the text where it appears, maybe in color.

I do NOT want to change the cite format in the text itself - i want the citations to appear as usual, like this[1][2].

I'm sure this has been asked (and answered) before, but I can't seem to locate it.

Comment: `showkeys` should do this. See also `refcheck`.

Comment: So I added \usepackage{natbib} at the top, cleaned out all the auxiliary files and built again, and now it works! Wonder why it didn't work without natbib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be a complete answer but here's what works for me after trial and error, they key point is ordering of the various `\usepackage` commands.

```
%Better refs
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[color]{showkeys}
```

and at the end of the document:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,My_Bib_File_Name}
```

It throws this warning, but not sure how to fix that yet.

```
The `cite' package should not be used(natbib) with natbib. Use option `sort' instead.
```